# express + cors() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, cors

I'm building a React application and I'm trying to make a call to [https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson](https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack%20johnson)

I have a helper called requestHelper.js which looks like :

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  const error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}

export default function request(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}
```

So I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack%20johnson. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My express server looks like this:

```
const ip = require('ip');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); 
app.use('/', express.static(resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'), 'index.html'))
});

// Start app
app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    return false;
  }

  const divider = '\n-----------------------------------';
  console.log('Server started ✓');
  console.log(`Access URLs:${divider}\n
  Localhost: http://localhost:${port}
        LAN: http://${ip.address()}:${port}
  ${divider}
  `);
});
```

I have tried using `mode: 'no-cors'` but is not actually what I need since the response is empty.

Am I doing something wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same origin policy kicks in when code hosted on A makes a request to B.

In this case A is your Express app and B is iTunes.

CORS is used to allow B to grant permission to the code on A to read the response.

You are setting up CORS on A. This does nothing useful since your site cannot grant your client side code permission to read data from a different site.

You need to set it up on B. Since you (presumably) do not work for Apple, you can't do this. Only Apple can grant your client side code permission to read data from its servers.

Read the data with server side code instead.

Comment: Understood! just a question.
Why will it work if I read the data from express, is not the same?

Comment: It isn't the same. Express doesn't have access to any of the identifying characteristics of the browser (such as cookies or the ability to send the request from the IP belonging to the user) that apple.com has access to.

Comment: Because express and Node are not executing inside a web browser. It's the browser, not the service, that enforces the single origin policy. The web service itself can only inform the browser if CORS is allowed. Node is javascript but standalone, it isn't a web browser and doesn't act like one.

Comment: thank you guys, you made me understand more about it.